# Do I need a permit to route ground wire through the walls to outlet?

Tags: receptacle, grounding

I have an ungrounded 2-prong outlet I'd like to upgrade to a 3 prong with proper grounding.

I'm in GA if region matters. If I bought a spool of the correct gauge solid copper wire, either bare wire or with green insulation, could I upgrade an outlet myself to be grounded, without proper training or permits?

I understand this would be a lot of work (potentially dangerous if I'm not careful to open all circuit breakers), but I'm willing to accept that.

I'd likely just route the new ground wire along side the existing hot/neutral cable through the walls/attic all the way to the circuit breaker panel and attach to the existing ground-bar-terminal-strip.

Comment: Has your authority having jurisdiction adopted the 2014 NEC?

Comment: Only the authority having jurisdiction could tell you if this type of work requires permits in your area.  There are strange rules everywhere-- for example my small town specifically exempts "any project valued under $2500" which is a giant loophole that has created many dangerous  things. So the only way to get this question answered is to go to your permit source and ask if you need one.

Comment: I agree with @tyson. Usually maintenance and repair (of existing branch circuits) no permit is required. But I have worked in states that require permits for almost all hard wired changes other than lighting, updating outlets and switches required permits.